# Boosted Dijkstra algorithm with pre-computed Shortest path tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

One of the most common graph algorithms is [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which identifies the weighted shortest path tree with a given node as root. The algorithm, when implemented with a good Fibonacci heap, [still outperforms in practical use cases other algorithms that should be theoretically asymptotically better](https://github.com/npruehs/thorup), such as [Thorup](http://forskning.diku.dk/PATH05/Thorup-1.pdf), which has a theoretical complexity of `O(E)`, with `E` being the number of edges in the graph, because of the constants involved in the Thorup's algorithm.

In some situations, for instance when parallelizing the computation of the [weighted diameter of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) which is done by running in parallel `N` instances of Dijkstra, with `N` being the number of nodes of the graph, one has to compute `N` shortest-path trees.

Suppose to have computed the shortest path tree for a node `i`, and now you want to compute the shortest path tree for the neighbouring node `j`. Having already computed the shortest path tree with as root the node `i`, represented either as a vector of predecessor or as a list of vectors of successors, is there any speedup possible by using the tree and avoiding the `O(log(n))` push and pop of nodes on the Dijkstra's queue?

For instance, [in the case of tendrils](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/networks-book/networks-book-ch13.pdf), the two shortest path trees would have a significant overlap: can this be exploited? Is there any paper working on this topic?

What about a random node `k`?